# Getting warnings for OverlayTrigger in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-bootstrap, react-fullstack

[Warning for Overlay Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbdqL.png)

I have used `OverlayTrigger` component of react-bootstrap, it gives warning as shown in the image above.

Code:

```
<OverlayTrigger delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }} overlay={"hello"} l="true">
   {children}
 </OverlayTrigger>
```

or

```
const value = "true";
<OverlayTrigger delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }} overlay={"hello"} l={value.toString()}>
   {children}
 </OverlayTrigger>
```

Tried using attribute l={"true"} or l={value.toString()}, yet not worked.

Expected the warning to be removed but it still existed in the browser.
Can anyone help remove this warning?